# How to use "LookAt" in local space?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to get a steering wheel to point at my controller in VR. When the "car" is rotated at 0 on the Y axis, everything works fine, but the steering wheel's rotation screws up when the "car" GameObject rotates. It seems like "lookat" is using world space to move the steering wheel, though I might be wrong. I have both the controller and steering wheel parented to the car. I've replicated the problem in a much simpler scene which is just a cube (steeringWheel) and a sphere (followGO) parented to a larger cube.

I have already tried using transformpoint, transformdirection, the inverse of both, local rotation and position. I can't seem to find anything that works.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class follow : MonoBehaviour
{

    public GameObject steeringWheel;
    public GameObject followGO;

    void Start()
    {

    }


    void Update()
    {
        steeringWheel.transform.LookAt(new Vector3(followGO.transform.position.x, followGO.transform.position.y, steeringWheel.transform.position.z), steeringWheel.transform.up);
    }
}
```

It's fine when I press play, the "wheel" points at the ball on the axis I asked it to.

But as soon as I rotate the parent Cube on the Y axis...

[image]

Comment: I'ld say the problem is rather that the VR controller gets its position in WorldSpace allways. You shouldn't parent it to any object you move by script or physics! Not a 100% sure but if I remember correctly it might even get its transform relative to the VR headset so it should be a child of the Camera or not be a child of anything at all.

Comment: I cannot understand the position to look, why use xy of the followGo but z of the steeringWheel itself?

Comment: @shingo probably because a steering wheel should only rotate on 1 axis ;)

Comment: @derHugo correct.

Comment: @derHugo i am trying to make a car for my game, and i want the steering wheel to follow the left controller.

Answer (score 2):

As you noticed correctly [`LookAt`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.LookAt.html) expects a `Vector3` coordinate in **world space**.

Your script works as expected as long as the car is not rotated itself since in that case the position difference between controller and wheel is (casually) in the world `Z` direction.

But if the car is twisted against the world you can not rely on simply using

```
new Vector3(followGO.transform.position.x, followGO.transform.position.y, steeringWheel.transform.position.z)
```

since it is not the world `Z` difference you want to eliminate anymore.

---

Instead you want to eliminate the local difference between controller and steering wheel in its local `Y` direction. You can use [`Transform.InverseTransformPoint`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.InverseTransformPoint.html) to convert a world coordinate into a local space coordinate and [`Transform.TransformPoint`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.TransformPoint.html) to convert a local coordinate to a world space coordinate:

```
// I just directly used Transform here
// to save a bit of coding later
public Transform steeringWheel;
public Transform followGO;

private void Update()
{
    // returns the position of followGO relative to the steeringwheel
    // but in the local transform space of the steering wheel itself
    var relativePosition = steeringWheel.InverseTransformDirection(followGO.position);

    // you want to eliminate the local difference in Y direction
    relativePosition.y = 0;

    // since you are right and LookAt expects a world position after eliminating the local Y difference 
    // we convert it back to world space
    var targetPosition = steeringWheel.TransformPoint(relativePosition);

    steeringWheel.transform.LookAt(targetPosition, steeringWheel.transform.up);
}
```

---

As you can see you now can rotate the car however you like and the steering wheel will always have its `Z` axis looking towards the controller.

[image]

---

For comparing if you want: [example.unitypackage](http://ul.to/lolmc4pt)

Comment: unfortunately this did not work for me. also, i am using c#, so i dont think `var` works (i corrected it to Vector3). when i ran it, the wheel completely bugged out.

Comment: this is `c#` .. the compiler "knows" which value type is returned by `InverseTransformDirection` and `TransformPoint` so automatically converts the `var` to `Vector3` internally. It perfectly worked for me as you can see so it's hard to tell why it doesn't for you. Did you try my other comment and make the VR controller not a child of the car?

Comment: O wait .. I just noticed that one thing I changed was using `public Transform` fields for the Inspector instead of `GameObject`

Comment: yeah i noticed that

Comment: i tried unparenting the "looktowards" GO in my example. still glitched out, wheel spazzed between two different directions (neither of which were correct)

Comment: Your example isn't working somehow? The wheel just snaps whenever it passes a certain point.

Comment: ... whell if you only change the X coordinate yes ... did you try to move the controller anywhere else on all axis? And if you want it upright than before hitting play rotate the wheel however you want the Y axis to be positioned

Comment: oh, it worked. strange, i dont remember it working before. im just a bit stupid i guess lol. ill try integrating your code into my main proj.

Comment: so i tried integrating the code into my main project and when i tried it, the wheel only moved a little bit and in the opposite direction it should have. it's most likely a problem on my end, though.